# Servlet 3.0: How to off-load Async processing to a different JVM?

Tags: java, servlets, java-ee-6, distributed-computing, servlet-3.0

Servlet 3.0 allows the 'request' thread (or 'main' thread) to delegate long-running processing to some other thread, so as to free itself to receive more requests. Agreed. 
That is, we are achieving scalability (of requests) by utilizing multi-threading.

But this requires that my 'Servlet container JVM' is capable of such processing.
What if I have a multi-tiered architecture where the 'Servlet container JVM' is only the entry point, while the logic for servicing requests lies somewhere else in some other JVM (henceforth called as 'Service JVM' in this post).

What if I want to post the incoming 'request' (or atleast the relevant attributes of the request) to a JMS queue and let the 'request' be grabbed and processed by one out of a pool of 'Service JVMs' ? Wouldnt it be better to delegate the responsibility of sending the 'response' (say as JSON) also to this Service JVM ?

I dont think 'AsyncContext' can be passed meaningfully outside of the Servlet container JVM. So, how to really delegate request-processing and response-sending, to be done by distributed services (JVMs) ?

In terms of code/pseudo-code, my question is:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/AsyncServlet", asyncSupported=true)
public class AsyncServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        AsyncContext asyncCtx = request.startAsync();
        // Put the asyncCtx in a JMS queue so as to be picked by another 
        // service JVM that can really service this request.
        // return back to receiving requests and dont worry abt sending a response
        // The service JVM will take care of sending the appropriate response
        // as it has the data necessary for the response.
    }
}
```

One option seems to be to have Worker threads (in the Servlet container JVM) wait for responses from the Service JVMs. After a Service JVM does the actual processing, it can communicate the results (thru messages or otherwise) to the respective Worker thread, and have the Worker thread send the GET response.

I want to know if there is (am sure there shd be !) a better alternative than this, as this seems so convoluted !

Comment: Can't your `AsyncContext` just wait for a response from JMS and write it to the response?

Comment: Have you consider use of EJB's? And a cluster of backend servers?

Comment: Diogo, may be you are right with your suggestion. But am not versed in EJBs, except for some half-baked-knowledge that EJBs are bad ! But may be you can point me to a link which helps me understand how EJB addresses this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set context as async
2. Store context inside singleton bean
3. Send a jms request
4. Process jms request
5. Send jms reply
6. Get context for reply from the singleton bean
7. Send reply to client

You might want to set a timer for cleanup and you can replace jms with async one-way ejb calls

Comment: This sounds the same as what I had mentioned in the last part of my question. i.e a two-hop response. from the place where the request was really processed to a servlet container thread and then to the actual sender of the request (browser). Am looking for a better alternative. i.e a one-hop response. If thats possible at all.

Comment: I think one-hop response with different VMs will not be possible because the second VM is another process on the OS and can't send byte (response) to the same Socket that receive the request on the first VM.

Comment: Obviously you cant serialize the socket connection. Consider WebServices and ws-addressing, if you want to send reply directly from processing jvm.

Comment: Sami, If possible, can you pls add a couple more statements to guide on how this can be achieved using WebServices and ws-addressing ? Thanks !

Comment: Client would have to be a webservices client that provides reply to address using the ws-addressing. Servlet would pass the reply to adressi to processor which uses it to send reply back to client using a one-way ws call.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my client is a REST client or browser !